# Retrieve mulitiple data from database into an array php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I am trying to retrieve data from my database and I want it to be in an array form. Below is the code I used to retrieve data from database.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT latlong FROM terminal");
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))

print_r($row1);
```

And this is the result I am getting

```
Array ( [0] => 14.602501 ) Array ( [0] => 14.551996 )
```

It should be [0] and [1] right?

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This is because each value is fetched in every loop, it's not like all your values are being fetched at once. You could do `$rows[] = $row1[0];` and then `print_r($rows);` after the while loop for your desired output.

Comment: use MYSQL_BOTH in place of MYSQL_NUM. check http://in1.php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Comment: Thank you @ICanHasCheezburger your method worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT latlong FROM terminal");
$row = array();
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
{
 $row[] = $row1[0];
}
print_r($row);
```

But you should stop using deprecated functions. And start using PDO instead.
[PHP PDO Fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)